# Java change calculator output

Tags: java, calculator, computer-science

I am writing a code that reads a real number from standard input as a double, then takes that value and prints out the least amount of bills and coin it takes to make that amount. I am not sure how to get the code to print out the amount with pluralizing certain amounts when necessary. If someone could chime in I would really appreciate it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Changecalc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter amount) ");
     double amount = input.nextDouble();
     int amountInt = (int) (amount * 100);

     double tmp;
     if(amount >= 100)
         {
         tmp = (int) amount/100;
         System.out.println (tmp + "$100 bills");
         amount = amount % 100;
         }
     if(amount >= 50)
         {
         tmp = (int) amount/50;
         System.out.println (tmp + "$50 bills");
         amount = amount % 50;
         }
    if(amount >= 20)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/50;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$20 bills");
        amount = amount % 20;
    }
    if(amount >= 10)
    {
        tmp= (int) amount/50;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$10 bills");
        amount = amount % 10;
    }
    if(amount >= 5)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/5;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$5 bills");
        amount = amount % 5;
    }
    if(amount >= 1)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/1;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$1 bills");
        amount = amount % 1;
    }
    if(amount >= .25)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.25;
        System.out.println (tmp + "quater");
        amount = amount % .25;
    }
    if(amount >= .10)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.10;
        System.out.println (tmp + "dime");
        amount = amount % .10;
    }
    if(amount >= .05)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.05;
        System.out.println (tmp + "nickel");
        amount = amount % .05;
    }
    if(amount >= .01)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.01;
        System.out.println (tmp + "penny");
        amount = amount % 01;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't 70 equal 1x fifty and 1x twenty? Why is tmp a double when it's casted to an int anyways? Why is the amount multiplied by 100? I don't think the amount/x, works for x under 1.

Comment: oh shoot you got me thanks for point that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly right. Its just that when amount is >= 20, then you have

```
if(amount >= 20)
{
    tmp = (int) amount/50;
    System.out.println (tmp + "$20 bills");
    amount = amount % 20;
}
```

> Instead it should be

```
if(amount >= 20)
{
    tmp = (int) amount/20;
    System.out.println (tmp + "$20 bills");
    amount = amount % 20;
}
```

> Similar issue is when amount is >=10. You need to correct that as
>   well.

Apart from this, you need to have logic to print bill or bills(in case of multiple bills) and have similar logic for quater(s), dime(s), nickel(s) & penny/pennies

---

> For pluralising you can use something similar to following

```
if(amount >= 100){
     tmp = (int) amount/100;         
     if(tmp > 1.0){
         System.out.println (tmp + "$100 bills");
     } else{
         System.out.println (tmp + "$100 bill");
     }
     amount = amount % 100;
 }
```

Comment: Thats the part i need some help with, what type of print bill(s) would I use?

Comment: @patm If this resolved your query, then you can accept the answer

Comment: still having issue with the output: `Enter amount) 
10.25
1.0tens
0.0quarters`

Comment: @patm I am assuming that you haven't made similar changes for all other notes and coins. Have you?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code logic to print out the amount with pluralizing certain amounts. You could try the below code, it may help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class Changecalc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter amount) ");
     double amount = input.nextDouble();
     int amountInt = (int) (amount * 100);

     double tmp;
     if(amount >= 100)
         {
         tmp = (int) amount/100;
         System.out.println (tmp + "$100 bills");
         amount = amount % 100;
         }
     if(amount >= 50)
         {
         tmp = (int) amount/50;
         System.out.println (tmp + "$50 bills");
         amount = amount % 50;
         }
    if(amount >= 20)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/20;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$20 bills");
        amount = amount % 20;
    }
    if(amount >= 10)
    {
        tmp= (int) amount/10;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$10 bills");
        amount = amount % 10;
    }
    if(amount >= 5)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/5;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$5 bills");
        amount = amount % 5;
    }
    if(amount >= 1)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/1;
        System.out.println (tmp + "$1 bills");
        amount = amount % 1;
    }
    if(amount >= .25)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.25;
        System.out.println (tmp + "quater");
        amount = amount % .25;
    }
    if(amount >= .10)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.10;
        System.out.println (tmp + "dime");
        amount = amount % .10;
    }
    if(amount >= .05)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.05;
        System.out.println (tmp + "nickel");
        amount = amount % .05;
    }
    if(amount >= .01)
    {
        tmp = (int) amount/.01;
        System.out.println (tmp + "penny");
        amount = amount % .01;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong divisor. Use proper one like:

```
if(amount >= 20)
{
   tmp = (int) amount/20;
   System.out.println (tmp + "$20 bills");
   amount = amount % 20;
}
if(amount >= 10)
{
   tmp= (int) amount/10;
   System.out.println (tmp + "$10 bills");
   amount = amount % 10;
}
```

and not this:

```
tmp = (int) amount/50;
```

Here is what you can do print result in your format:

```
double tmp;
            String result = "Amount: ";

            if(amount >= 100)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/100;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$100 bills ";
                amount = amount % 100;
            }
            if(amount >= 50)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/50;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$50 bills ";
                amount = amount % 50;
            }
            if(amount >= 20)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/20;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$20 bills ";
                amount = amount % 20;
            }
            if(amount >= 10)
            {
                tmp= (int) amount/10;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$10 bills ";
                amount = amount % 10;
            }
            if(amount >= 5)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/5;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$5 bills ";
                amount = amount % 5;
            }
            if(amount >= 1)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/1;
                result = result + (int)tmp + "$1 bills ";
                amount = amount % 1;
            }
            if(amount >= .25)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/.25;
                result = result + (int)tmp + " qurters ";
                amount = amount % .25;
            }
            if(amount >= .10)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/.10;
                result = result + (int)tmp + " dimes ";
                amount = amount % .10;
            }
            if(amount >= .05)
            {
                tmp = (int) amount/.05;
                result = result + (int)tmp + " nickels ";
                amount = amount % .05;
            }
            if(amount >= .01) {
                tmp = (int) amount / .01;
                result = result + (int)tmp + " penny ";
                amount = amount % 01;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Here is sample run:

> Enter amount)  124 Amount: 1$100 bills 1$20 bills 4$1 bills

You can do slight modifications as per your requirements.

Comment: oh that was an accident thanks for point it out. My question is how i set up a print statement for the entire thing like $70 = 1 fifty , 1 twenty